# How to create multiple copies of a java application in Docker Compose file for ribbon load balancing?

Tags: java, docker-compose, port, load-balancing, scale

How do you set up a docker-compose file for a spring application that has client-side load balancing with ribbon? Say I have in my application.properties file specify server.port=8000. I need to create 3 additional copies of the service that run on different ports than 8000 (exposing or not). How do you achieve this by not generate different images or use an orchestration tool?

Comment: did you try docker-compose up -d --scale myapp=3 myapp

Comment: Inside docker-compose.yml
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 9

Comment: @RKernel Thanks for your response, but I believe the command (docker-compose up --scale) will create three services with same port (which I specify in application.properties file) and the second involves docker swarm and is ignored by simply using docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  myapp:
    ports:
      - "8000"
#port 8000 is mapped to a random portnumber

#    deploy:
#      mode: replicated
#      replicas: 3
```

docker-compose up -d --scale myapp=3 myapp